# How to print text inside <%= %>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there an easier way to do the following?

```
<% if (Model.XY == 10) { %>
    10
<%} else { %>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("10", "SetXY", new { [...] }) %>
<% } %>
```

I'm thinking about something like

```
<%= Model.XY == 10 ? "10" : Html.ActionLink() %>
```

Comment: There is not a direct conversion from string to MvcHtmlString, you would need to use: <%= Model.XY == 10 ? new MvcHtmlString("10") : Html.ActionLink() %>

Comment: Thanks, Nick.

It seems that using

    MvcHtmlString.Create("10")

is recommended.

Comment: @NickBork You should add that as an actual answer so you get the credit you deserve and the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: It was really meant to be a comment to see if there was something more that Fria might have needed. I've included the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionLink helper returns MvcHtmlString. The value "10" is a string. There is no implicit conversion between the MvcHtmlString and String/string.

To fix that you should create a MvcHtmlString out of a string by using:

```
 new MvcHtmlString("10");
```

From there you can simplify your code as:

```
 <%= Model.XY == 10 ? new MvcHtmlString("10") : Html.ActionLink("10", "SetXY", new { [...] }) %>
```